# how to do update and submit functionality on same button

Tags: angular

I am doing edit functionality after edit it is giving records in the form and in this form I want to check if `id` is `null` then submit button should be active else update button but at a time it is checking only one either submit or update.

In submit I have checked if `id` is present or not if present goto update else goto submit.

```
if (id1 !== '') { 
  submit();
}
else {
  update();
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Is it working or not? Showing error?

Comment: first of all you need to understand that null and '' is not the same.
second we gonna need to see more code because I dont understand whats wrong.

Comment: The above code suppose to work. Is it working or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the id in the if the condition for *`null`* and *`undefined`* like:

```
if (!id1) { // that means `id` is either null or undefined
  submit();
}
else {
  update();
}
```

[`Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c5e9b8)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator also. just check the following code

```
this.id ? this.update() : this.submit()
```